# How do I loop through a number of variables and perform operations on them in R?

Tags: r

Suppose that I have 30 tsv files of twitter data, say Google, Facebook and LlinkedIn, etc. I want to perform a set of operations on all of them, and was wondering if I can do so using a loop.

Specifically, I know that I can create variables using a loop, such as

```
index = c("fb", "goog", "lkdn")
for (i in 1:length(index)){
     file_name = paste(names[i], ".data", sep = "")
     assign(file_name, read.delim(paste(index$report_id[i],     
            "-tweets.tsv", sep = ""), header = T, 
            stringsAsFactors = F))
}
```

But how do I perform operations to all these data files in the loop? For example, if I want to order the datafiles using `data[order(data[,4]), ]`, how do I make sure that the data file name is changed in each iteration of the loop? Thanks!

Comment: 1. `names` is a base function, it's not wise to use that as a variable. 2. what's `n`?

Answer (score 0):

Build a function that does all of the operations you need it to do and then create a loop calling that function instead. If you insist on using assign to create lots of variables (not a great practice for this very reason) then try something like:

```
files <- dir("path/to/files", pattern = "*.tsv")

fileFunction <- function(x){
  df <- read.delim(x, sep = "\t", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)
  df <- df[order(df[,4]),]
  return(df)
}

for (a in files){
  assign(a, fileFunction(a))
}
```